# Adding variable hours to timestamp in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have one column Start_Time with a timestamp, and one column Time_Zone_Offset, an integer. How can I add the Time_Zone_Offset to Start_Time as a number of hours?

Example MyTable:

```
id  Start_Time            Time_Zone_Offset

1   2020-01-12 00:00:00     1
2   2020-01-12 00:00:00     2
```

Desired output:

```
id  Local_Start_Time

1   2020-01-12 01:00:00
2   2020-01-12 02:00:00
```

Attempt:

```
SELECT id, Start_time + INTERVAL time_zone_offset HOURS AS Local_Start_Time
FROM MyTable
```

This doesn't seem to work, and I can't use `from_utc_timestamp` as I don't have the actual timezone details, just the time-zone offset at the time being considered.

Comment: might be a typo but it should be "HOUR" not "HOURS" in "SELECT id, Start_time + INTERVAL time_zone_offset HOURS AS Local_Start_Time
FROM MyTable"

Comment: @BenoitF Sadly it isn't, I can also successfully run 
"SELECT id, Start_time + INTERVAL 1 HOURS AS Local_Start_Time
FROM MyTable"
i.e. it's the change to the column referenced instead of a fixed value that seems to cause a problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Hope you are using pyspark)

In deed, coudn't make it work with SQL, I manage to get to the result by converting to timestamp, its probably not the best way but it works (i proceeded step by step to make sure the references were working, thought i would need a user defined function, but apparently not)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,explode,lit
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df2 = df.withColumn("Start_Time", F.unix_timestamp("Start_Time"))
df2.show()
df3 = df.withColumn("Start_Time", F.unix_timestamp("Start_Time") + df["Time_Zone_Offset"]*60*60)
df3.show()
df4 = df3.withColumn('Start_Time', F.from_unixtime("Start_Time", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:00:00")).show()
```

Comment: Thanks Benoit! I actually ended up using a UDF since I didn't want to convert my table to a dataframe and back again. Shame that there's no native way to do this with Spark SQL.

Comment: Thank you so much, I also had the same problem and now it has resolved.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else coming to this question and using Spark SQL via Databricks, the [`dateadd`](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/dateadd.html) function works in the same way as most other SQL languages:

```
select dateadd(microsecond,30,'2022-11-04') as microsecond
      ,dateadd(millisecond,30,'2022-11-04') as millisecond
      ,dateadd(second     ,30,'2022-11-04') as second
      ,dateadd(minute     ,30,'2022-11-04') as minute
      ,dateadd(hour       ,30,'2022-11-04') as hour
      ,dateadd(day        ,30,'2022-11-04') as day
      ,dateadd(week       ,30,'2022-11-04') as week
      ,dateadd(month      ,30,'2022-11-04') as month
      ,dateadd(quarter    ,30,'2022-11-04') as quarter
      ,dateadd(year       ,30,'2022-11-04') as year
```

### Output

| microsecond | millisecond | second | minute | hour | day | week | month | quarter | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-04T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2022-11-04T00:00:00.030+0000 | 2022-11-04T00:00:30.000+0000 | 2022-11-04T00:30:00.000+0000 | 2022-11-05T06:00:00.000+0000 | 2022-12-04T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2023-06-02T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2025-05-04T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2030-05-04T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2052-11-04T00:00:00.000+0000 |

Comment: It's just specific to Databricks implementation of Spark, and is not included in General Distribution.

Comment: @ManuBatham That is correct, which is why I started this answer by clarifying *"For anyone else coming to this question and using Spark SQL via Databricks"*

Answer (score 3):

Beginning from Spark 3.0, you may use the `make_interval(years, months, weeks, days, hours, mins, secs)` function if you want to add intervals using values from other columns.

```
SELECT 
    id
    , Start_time + make_interval(0, 0, 0, 0, time_zone_offset, 0, 0) AS Local_Start_Time
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding an alternative to Benoit's answer using a python UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

# Defining pyspark function to add hours onto datetime
def addHours(my_datetime, hours):
    # Accounting for NULL (None in python) values
    if (hours is None) or (my_datetime is None):
        adjusted_datetime = None
    else:
        adjusted_datetime = my_datetime + timedelta(hours = hours)
    return adjusted_datetime

# Registering the function as a UDF to use in SQL, and defining the output type as 'TimestampType' (this is important, the default is StringType)
sqlContext.udf.register("add_hours", addHours, TimestampType());
```

followed by:

```
SELECT id, add_hours(Start_Time, Time_Zone_Offset) AS Local_Start_Time
FROM MyTable
```